# Battery issue - backup problem?

Tags: iphone, backup, battery

I recently bought a new iPhone 6, because my iPhone 5 had some weird battery issues: when I was on 3G or 4G, the battery would literally go down from 50% to 10% in like 10 minutes. On the Wi-Fi, it was pretty OK.

Right now, with my new Phone, I was expecting way better battery results. But weirdly enough, it's still pretty bad, though the phone is new.

I went to the Apple Store a couple of weeks back with my iPhone 5 and the guy told me that it may be a software issue (related to my backup, which I put on my iPhone 6) and not a hardware issue (don't worry I didn't buy the new iPhone just because of that).

Anyways, I was wondering if that could be a logical explanation?
And then, I would like to try completely factory restoring my phone to check but there are some settings like the wifi passwords, etc. that I'd like to keep...how can I transfer them without the backup?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sadly the answer is manually.  I had a similar issue when went from a 4 to 5s.  Eventually I sat down with a piece of paper and pen and went through my phone in detail looking for what I needed.  The biggest loss was the wifi networks I had joined over the years, but the clean setup did solve the battery problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I'll do it then...I'm pretty annoyed to lose some of those passwords but that's OK I guess. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first make a full backup and restore the new iPhone to **factory default**. Don't worry about your settings, it's stored in the backup so you can place it back if you miss something. *Or you could try this fix on the iPhone 5 first.*

**Problem resolved?**
If the problem is gone you shouldn't place the back-up back, as something might be damaged inside. You can now **manually** download every app and add the Wi-Fi settings.

Unfortunately: You cannot put any part of your back-up back, as it's damaged somehow.

**Please**
Please don't worry about Wi-Fi settings. You can always ask everyone for their passwords (at least in my circles) they're given out pretty easily. You rather have a fully functional phone and battery rather than all Wi-fi passwords, don't you?

<sub>Please note I didn't add an answer to when restoring to clean default does not fix your issue.</sub>